# how can I read data from a POST request body, when I write a web server using C

Tags: c, sockets, http, post, server

I am writing a **Web Server** in **C language**. When there is a **POST request received by my server, the server can use 'recv()' function to read the POST request. The code to read the request:

```
char buffer[1024];
memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
recv(client_socket,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0);
printf("buffer: %s", buffer);
```

the request looks like this:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8080
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
```

But I cannot read the body data of POST request. (the data is in the **form** submitted by client using **POST** method) How can I access these data?

Comment: HTTP 1.1 is based on TCP. TCP is a byte-stream protocol, where there's no beginnings or ends to the stream. This means a single `recv` call could receive less than what was passed in a single `send` call. Or from multiple calls to `send` (including partial data). You must be able to extract the header-fields from possible multiple calls to `recv`, then use the information received in the header (like `Content-Length`) to figure out the amount of body data to receive. And then possibly use more calls to `recv` to receive it.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I think I extracted all contents of header, including **Content-Lengrh: 10**. So it may mean that the length of body data is 10. But I only can know the length of body data, how can I know the actual value. For example, I use **HTML form** in client side and input string "ABC" in textarea of form, then submit the form to my server using POST. How can I read string "ABC" in my server side. Multiple calls to 'recv' just can read all content of header but not body?

Comment: @smallwhite: "Multiple calls to 'recv' just can read all content of header but not body?" -- That should not be the case. Calling `recv` in a loop should give you the entire HTTP response, including both the header and the body.

Comment: Thx a lot! the second call to ' recv ' read the body!

Comment: @smallwhite: You cannot rely on the first `recv` call getting the header and the second call getting the body. For example, the first call could give you half the header and the second call could give you the rest of the header and the start of the body. The only way to know where the header starts is by looking for an empty line, i.e. to look for `\r\n\r\n`.

Comment: Refer to [RFC 2616 Section 4.4](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-4.4)/[RFC 7230 Section 3.3.3](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3.3.3) for the rules you need to follow to determine the transfer size of an HTTP request, so you know when to stop reading it. Call `recv()` in a loop until you reach the `\r\n\r\n` that terminates the headers, then parse the headers to determine if a body is present and what transfer format it uses, then `recv()` the body in a loop until you reach the end of the request. Only then can you parse the body according to the `Content-Type` header

Comment: A posted HTML webform will use either [`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#application/x-www-form-urlencoded) or [`multipart/form-data`](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7578) as the `Content-Type` of the body data.  Parse the body according to the specs of those formats.

Comment: @Andreas Wenzel Thanks, I got the idea.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau May I know whether I can use "text/plain" to be the Content-Type? It sends the original text in form instead of encoded text. If I use "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", it is difficult for me to decode the text on my server-side.

Comment: @smallwhite [HTML5 supports submitting a webform in `text/plain` format](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#plain-text-form-data). HTML4 does not. Even with `text/plain`, the text is still encoded, just *slightly less* than `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Both formats are not difficult to decode, though.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: That is a very good link that you posted. Especially of interest is this part: "Payloads using the `text/plain` format are intended to be human readable. They are not reliably interpretable by computer, as the format is ambiguous (for example, there is no way to distinguish a literal newline in a value from the newline at the end of the value)."

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I have never seen a webserver use `text/plain` for a webform in practice.